# Polymorphic database design : does this approach have a name?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a base enitiy (items) that will host a vast range of item types (>200) with totaly different properties. I want a clean portable and fast solution and have come up with an idea that maby has a name I'm unaware of.

Here it goes:

- items-entity holds base class fields + additional fields for subclass fields but with dummie-names, ItemID,ItemNo,ItemTypeID,int1,int2,dec1,dec2,dec3,str1,str2
- referenced itemtype-record holds name of type and child enity (1:n):
- itemtypefields [itemtypeid,name,type,realfield]
  example in [53,MaxPressure,dec,dec3]

It's limitations:

- hard to estimate field requirements in baseclass
- harder to add domains/checkconstraints based on child type
- need application layer to translate tagged sql to real query
- Only possible to query one type at a time since shared attributes may be defined to different "real-fields".

3rd bullet explained:

```
select ItemNo,_MaxPressure_ from items where ItemTypeID=10 and _MaxPressure_>42
should translate to:
select ItemNo,dec3 as MaxPressure from items where ItemType=10 and dec3>42
```

(can't do that with sp's or udf's right - or whould it be possible?)

But benefits of:

- Performance
- Ease of CRUD-operations
- Easier to sort/filter at application level.

Now - does it have a name?

Comment: I doubt that this method has any of the advantages that you claim, least of all performance.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, which would be the alternate method - xml-field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This antipattern is called [One True Lookup Table](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/).

In a relational database, each column needs to be defined as one logical type.  I don't mean one SQL data type like INT or VARCHAR, I mean everything in that column from start to finish must be from the same set of values, and you should be able to tell one value apart from another value.

You can't put shoe size and average temperature and threads per inch into the same column of a given table, and still call it a relation.

Basically, your database would not be a database at all -- it would be a *spreadsheet*.

Read almost any book by C. J. Date, such as [SQL and Relational Theory](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022879.do) for a proper explanation of relations and types.

---

Re your comment:

> Read the Q again before lecuturing about elementary books and mocking about semi structured data.

Okay, I have re-read your post.

The classic use of One True Lookup Table isn't *exactly* what you're doing, but what you're doing shares the same problems with OTLT.

Suppose you have "MaxPressure" stored in column `dec3` for ItemType 10.  Suppose there are a fixed set of valid choices for the value of MaxPressure, and you want to put those in another lookup table, so that no one can enter an invalid MaxPressure value.

Now:  declare a foreign key constraint on dec3 referencing your MaxPressures lookup table. *You can't* -- the problem is that the foreign key constraint applies to the dec3 column in *all* rows, not just those rows where ItemType is 10.

The reason is that you're storing more than one set of values in a single column.  The same problem arises for any other kind of constraint -- unique constraints, check constraints, even NOT NULL.  And you can't declare a DEFAULT value for the column either, because you probably have a different correct default for each ItemType (and some ItemTypes have no default for that attribute).

The reason that I referred to the C. J. Date book is that he gives a crisp definition for a *type*:  it's a named finite set, over which the equality operation is defined.  That is, you can tell if the value "42" on one row is the same as the value "42" on another row.  In a relational column, that must be true because they must come from the same original set of values.  In your table, `dec3` could have the value "42" when it's MaxPressure, but "42" for another ItemType when it's threads per inch.  Therefore they aren't the *same* value "42".  If you had a unique constraint, these two 42's would not be considered duplicates. If you had a foreign key, each of the different 42's would reference a different lookup table, etc.

*What you're doing is not a valid relational database design.*

Don't bristle at my referring you to a resource on relational database design unless you understand that.

Comment: As I understand OTLT, it's a child table witch one row for each attribute. That's another deal. I'm storing attributes in base-class and using lookups only to solve the label of the attribute.

Comment: No, that's Entity-Attribute-Value, it's something different.  You're doing OTLT, which is to store a bunch of lookups for unrelated sets in one table.

Comment: no i'm not. Read the Q again before lecuturing about elementary books and mocking about semi structured data.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts, it appricated (but I do have some issues with all do's and dont's circulating). I fully understand all the shortcomings regardning contraints etc. But. What's the option here? Create and maintain >200 sub-entities would be an adminstration-nightmare.